# Three.js loaded .obj does not show after updated to r67

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

My initial version of three.js is r62, and I can load and show my .obj Objects with .mtl file to the scene correctly.

However, after updating the three.js to r67 (with the OBJMTL loader), my object become unable to render on the scene. I tried to revert everything as the same as the code inside example in [webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~lizy/mrdoob-three.js-ef5f05d/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html) from the official:

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
//The exmaple object
//loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', 'obj/male02/male02_dds.mtl'
//My object             
loader.load( '../../my_model/my_model.obj"
, "../../my_model/my_model.mtl"
    ,function(object){
        object.position.y = - 80;
        scene.add( object );
    }
);
```

It comes very wield that the example object comes from webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html can be loaded and showed in r67. But for my .obj file, the chrome console message shows that the files are successfully loaded, but it does not show up on the scene.

What would be the problem here? Does there are any limitation/format differences between r62 and r67 in importing .obj and .mtl files?

Looking forward for help, many thanks!

Comment: are you sure you're using r67 version of the loader? does it work for other objects? the example sure seems to work. i'm not aware of support for anything being dropped in obj & mtl but there's been quite many changes otherwise in three.js between those releases.

Comment: #antont Sorry for late reply, it doesn't work for other objects created by me either. The browser console stated the .obj and .mtl are successfully loaded, but nothing appears on the scene. Only replacing the object to the example one works.

Comment: perhaps create an issue to the three.js tracker with links to a working version with r62 and broken with r67 with the same object. or debug by stepping the parsing & loading thru in the debugger.